# Freemarker - Reload Template

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, freemarker

I have a page whereby I am including a freemarker FTL in this way:
`<#include "header.ftl">`

Now, the page that it is in does not reload as it's a one pager.  However, I would like that at a certain point I refresh header.ftl without doing a full page refresh.  Is this possible by any chance?  I am new to FTL.

Comment: Where do you put data on the context for that template?

Comment: @RobertMoskal  it is put on the main page, where the header.ftl is being included

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two serverside endpoints, one for the whole page and another for the fragment(s).

You can then use an [ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) request to refresh the fragment (eg [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/))

Comment: do you have an example of this or maybe can point me to a tutorial for it?

Comment: You haven't mentioned which serverside web framework you are using. Spring MVC? Webwork? Struts 1/2? This will have a huge impact on the implementation details. Also the clientside framework (jquery, backbone, etc).

Comment: server side it's Spring MVC and client side it's jquery

Comment: So just add another endpoint to your controller for the fragment. And hit it via jquery ajax. And update a clientside div with the result